# Should I take care of SQL query optimisation in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, query-optimization

In MySQL DBMS, should the programmer take care of the query optimisation (like choosing the optimum relational algebra query) when writing the SQL? or it is the responsibility of the DBMS.

To explain more what I mean. In this example:

`SELECT * FROM Staff s, Branch b
WHERE s.branchNo = b.branchNo AND (s.position = 'Manager' AND b.city = 'London')`

Does the query optimiser of MySQL decide efficiently how to distribute the brackets of the predicates (the WHERE clause)? (e.g. depending on the size of each table, or any info from the system statistics)

Comment: So you are asking, who should do the optimization, the programmer or the computer?  A computer is stupid, only does what its told to do.  Which would you think would be better?

Comment: It depends of what you mean by query optimisation. If we are talking about avoding using non index functions, regexp et cetera then programmer should take care about such responsibility. In other way when programmer would like for exmaple to enforce join order on RDBMS it would be bad practise.

Comment: @paqogomez I think the answer is potentially more nuanced than that.

Comment: @Strawberry i'm sure it is, but how can we tell?

Comment: thanks of the answers, I extended the question with an example to explain more what I mean.

Comment: First off stiop using implicit joins. THey are a SQL antipattern. Next use the () as you need to for clarity for the person who will maintain the code. If you havea an OR clasue anywhere inteh the query make sure you use the (). Next yes it is your responsiblity to write code that can perform well.  Read up on performance tuning, there are many wasy to write theh same code and you shouod know the ones that perform best as database performance is critical and it takes no longer to write performant code than nonperformant once you know what it is. Read up on performance tuning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the programmer's responsibility; this "responsibility" cannot be transferred to the DBMS.

As mysterious and magical as the MySQL query optimizer may appear to be, it's only a computer program. It can only do what it is programmed to do. It doesn't invoke any "magic" to transform inefficient SQL queries into efficient ones.

As a simple example, consider these two queries (assuming `dt` is a DATE, DATETIME or TIMESTAMP column in `t`):

one:

```
SELECT t.foo
  FROM t 
 WHERE t.dt >= '2015-01-05'
   AND t.dt <  '2015-01-05' + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

two:

```
SELECT t.foo
  FROM t 
 WHERE DATE(t.dt) = '2015-01-05'
```

These queries specify the same result. With one of these queries, the MySQL optimizer can opt to make use of an index range scan operation. With the other, it can't.

The programmer has the "responsibility" to provide SQL text that allows the DBMS to make efficient use of resources.

---

Consider another simple example:

```
 SELECT t.foo
   FROM t
  WHERE t.foo = 'bar'
```

vs.

```
 SELECT s.foo
   FROM ( SELECT t.* FROM t ) s
  WHERE s.foo = 'bar'
```

vs.

```
 SELECT t.foo
   FROM t
  HAVING t.foo = 'bar'
```

These three queries specify the same result, but if we look at the EXPLAIN output, we will see that we don't get identical query plans.

---

Bottom line: If we are going to choose between the "programmer" or the "query optimizer", to assign "responsibility" for efficient use of resources... it's clear from just a few simple examples that the query optimizer is not up to that task. It can only do what it's been programmed to do. So, if we have to choose, the ultimate responsibility lies with the programmer.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** In this example:

```
SELECT * FROM Staff s, Branch b WHERE s.branchNo = b.branchNo 
AND (s.position = 'Manager' AND b.city = 'London')
```

Does the query optimizer of MySQL decide efficiently how to distribute the brackets of the predicates (the WHERE clause)? (e.g. depending on the size of each table, or any info from the system statistics)?

**A:** To the query optimizer, a predicate is a predicate. Superfluous parens around predicates don't confuse the optimizer. (The parens in your example will be discarded, they don't change the query plan.

Kudos on using table aliases. (That makes both the query and the EXPLAIN output shorter, and easier to read.)

But ditch the old-school comma syntax for the join operation. Use the `JOIN` keyword in place of the comma. And move the join predicates to an ON clause. Also, specify the minimum set of columns you need returned; don't return use `*` and return columns you don't need. In this example, there's no need to return both `s.branchNo` and `b.branchNo`, one of those can be omitted, and make the resultset smaller. (Specifying the columns to be returned also enables the DBA to make effective choices for covering indexes.)

Ensure you have appropriate indexes, and review the EXPLAIN output to understand the operations that MySQL is going to perform. (Better yet, use EXPLAIN EXTENDED and SHOW WARNINGS, to get a better idea of what MySQL is doing with your statement)

```
SELECT s.branchNo
     , s.position
     , b.city
  FROM Staff s
  JOIN Branch b
    ON b.branchNo = s.branchNo
 WHERE s.position = 'Manager'
   AND b.city = 'London'
```

As a first cut for best performance, we're going to want an index that has a leading column referenced in one of the equality predicates in the WHERE clause (if that's restricting the resultset to less than 10% or 20% of the rows in the table. For example:

```
... ON Branch (city)
... ON Staff (branchNo, position)
```

If we don't have suitable indexes, then MySQL is going to resort to doing nested loop scans. We won't notice any performance issue on small sets. But on larger sets, those operations are going to turn out to be inefficient enough to eat our lunch.

Unfortunately, the optimizer isn't going to automatically create the most appropriate indexes. It's the programmer's responsibility to make sure that suitable indexes are available.

The InnoDB storage engine keeps the statistics up-to-date, it does a decent job of that. And doing an `ANALYZE TABLE` on MyISAM tables will ensure that the optimizer has reasonable statistics available.

To summarize: we can't just throw some SQL text at the optimizer and expect that we are going to get optimum performance out of MySQL. So, this responsibility ultimately falls on the programmer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer spencer7593. But to explain more what I mean, in this example:
`
SELECT * FROM Staff s, Branch b
WHERE s.branchNo = b.branchNo AND (s.position = 'Manager' AND b.city = 'London')
`
Do the query optimiser of MySQL decide efficiently how to distribute the brackets of the predicates (the WHERE clause)? (e.g. depending on the size of each table, or any info from the system statistics)?

Comment: @SBay parentheses here mean nothing. `()` operator's aim is to change the operator priority. In this particular case we have `AND` in both cases so parentheses will be eliminated during query simplification. Short circuiting does not work in SQL, since it's declarative, not imperative.

Comment: @zerkms sure it makes no difference from the high level language (SQL) perspective I misused the word brackets where it is not relevant here; but this query can be decomposed to three different (equivalent) relational algebra queries, one of them with cartesian product and the other two are with natural joins. Does the MySQL decompose the query the same way and select the most optimum of the three?

Comment: @SBay: mysql does not take into account order of predicates. So for the given query it will choose the execution plan that it thinks (according the current schema and statistics) to be the most optimal one.

Comment: I concur with zerkms. A predicate is a predicate is a predicate. It doesn't matter what order they are in or whether they are in the `ON` clause (of an `INNER JOIN`) or in the `WHERE` clause. (The parens do change the order of precedence for a combination boolean AND/OR operations, e.g. **`(a AND b) OR c`** vs **`a AND (b OR c)`**. But with `a AND b AND c`, you can add parens around whichever parts and it won't make a difference... a predicate is a predicate is a predicate. In selecting the access plan, the cardinality/statistics and the availability of suitable indexes DOES influence the opti

Comment: @zerkms ,spencer7593 thank you. This is what I wanted to know.